# C# FileStream теряет данные

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

делал приложение на .net core для передачи данных по сети, но постоянно терялись последние байты. Методом тыка понял что filestream не пишет байты если их меньше чем размер единицы распределения жесткого диска(В моем случае 4кб). Самое интересное что в .net framework 4 все работает

```
{
    FileStream fstream = new FileStream(@"D:\note.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
    Random rd = new Random();
    
    byte[] array = new byte[500];
    rd.NextBytes(array);

    fstream.Write(array, 0, array.Length);   
}
```

Для проверки написал метод, который рандомно заполняет txt документ, с 4096 байт на .net core работает но если поставить значение ниже то нет. Может я чего то не понимаю, или .net core так и должен работать?

Comment: А где закрытие потока Close/Dispose или Flush, который заставит сбросить буфер на диск?

Comment: Спасибо тебе огромное, я еще учусь и особого внимание этому не придал. Еще раз спасибо за ответ, и за пояснение что он значит. Просто больше всего я не понимал, почему в .net framework работает а в .net core нет

Comment: `using FileStream fstream = new FileStream(...);` такое объявление с `using` само задиспозит `FileStream`.

Comment: Можно еще так `using FileStream fstream = File.Create(@"D:\note.txt");` - выглядит аккуратнее, тоже создаст или перезапишет файл.

Comment: "Последний байты" – это много или мало? Можно конкретные цифры, или, если кол-во рандомно, примерный диапазон кол-ва последних байт.

Comment: Странно, я запустил на .NET Core и у меня всё работает – копирует все 500 байтов. Не с `FileStream`, а с вашим кодом что-то не так. Я тестировал, создав консольное приложение и скопировав внутрь метода `Main` ваш код (добавив `using`) – всё работает; проверял через Hex Editor Neo.

Comment: Здесь нужно попробовать вариант с явным вызовом Flush. Насколько я понимаю, NET Core пытается экономить вызовы записи на жд, ожидая возможное появление дополнительных данных, так как в случае, если данные появятся, придется перезаписывать полную единицу.

Comment: @RustySkull вопрос можно считать закрытым – автор не знает (или не знал) зачем нужен `using`